# Xero Invoice types

Tags: xero-api

I'm trying to upload invoices to Xero via their API. However in the schema under 'Type' it lists the possible enums and says 'See Invoice Types', but I can not find the description of the types anywhere. The types aren't described in the web documentation or in the swagger doc.

[image]

Does anybody know where I can find exactly what these types mean?

Comment: I hadn't noticed that they've changed all the documentation site. Prior to this change, the invoice types were explained. I can only hope that where it says "See: Invoice Types" it will soon become a link to an explanation. ACCPAY and ACCREC are fairly straightforward, they're either accounts-payable (purchase) or accounts-receivable (sales) invoices.

Answer (score 2):

yes we are going through the beta release of documentation that is generated by our Open API Spec. We will be fixing soon to make the descriptions of these types easier to find but attached is the previous list. of the descriptions you are after.

I believe the 6 extra types might be related to legacy Invoice data that needed to be represented for deserialization purposes.. Digging into that answer now.

[image: invoice types]

I've also started a thread to update publicly on this issue. Thanks for bringing to attention and will make sure to update this thread on the long term solve. @droopsnoot appreciate your activity as always :P
https://github.com/XeroAPI/Xero-OpenAPI/issues/426

Comment: It may be that some of those types are internally used - I know that if I send a bank transaction to Xero a pseudo-invoice is generated (I was trying to control the invoice number that it gets) and maybe that has the type "ARPREPAYMENT". I don't have my Xero trial set up at the moment so I can't check.

Comment: Yeah that is actually correct. The invoice Object has some inheritance going on with Bank Transactions and those are possible types. @mark for your purposes I think you can safely assume in POSTing an invoice to only use Accounts Payable or Accounts Receivable.